# spring async can not add "waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" in <task:executor/>

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

```
<task:executor id="ACTIVATION-2000" 
          pool-size="#[ACTIVATION_THREAD_NUMBER]" 
          queue-capacity="20000" 
          waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown="true"/>
```

In an example as above when i add `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` property. I get below error since xsd does not support. Why we can not add `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` in above naming.

Attribute `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` is not allowed to appear in element `task:executor`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Using BeanPostProcessor with below implementation can fix the problem

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object object, String arg1)
        throws BeansException {
    if(object instanceof ThreadPoolTaskScheduler)
        ((ThreadPoolTaskScheduler)object).setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return object;
}
```